# Can you animate Banners ads with the Google Play lib?

Tags: android, admob

I've correctly implemented a banner add at the top of my main activity (using the Google Play lib) and it works fine. I also have some animations play on the text and buttons on this screen, but if I try to apply them to the adview, they don't do anything. Is there something special to get the adView to animate as I want? Thanks.

Edit: To clarify this is how I'm calling the animation:

```
// Create an ad.
adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

mainLayout.addView(adView);

inFromTop = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.infromtop);
adView.startAnimation(inFromTop);
```

Comment: Maybe place the `adView` in a container (let's say another layout - L1) and animate L1 itself?

Comment: How would I add it to a container since it's done programmatically? Would you just call .addView on another element in the xml layout file?

Comment: No, you can't do that in the layout file. You can do this programmatically, the same way you add the `AdView` to the `mainLayout`. The difference is that you will have to add the `adView` to the `RelativeLayout` (RL1) and then add the RL1 to the mainLayout liek so: `RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);`, also `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
`, then do `rl.addView(adView, param);` and then `mainLayout.addView(rl);`, if the `mainLayout` is ok to receive it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make layout for banner, and set banner visibility to gone.

Then, make an ad listener, when ad is ready, set banner visibility to visible (programmatically).

```
final AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() { // ads is loaded
            super.onAdLoaded();
            adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // banner visible
            adView.startAnimation(animFadeIn); // make animation
        }
    });
```